# update columns of SQL Server 2008 DB Table based on value in one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to implement a functionality of trial license expiration. I have created `Membership` table with the following columns :

- `Registration_Date`,
- `Trial_Expiration_Date`
- `Trial_Expired` (Values: Y/N).

The trial duration two weeks.

Can you please help me write a `stored procedure` to:

1. Update Columns `Trial_Expiration_Date = Registration_Date + 14.` I will insert the values in `"Registration_Date"` column as soon as the registration is successful.
2. If Date difference of today and `Trial_Expiration_Date` is 0, updated the field `"Trial_Expired"` to `'Y'`.

I am using a SQL server 2008 database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression in an update statement

```
UPDATE Membership
SET    Trial_Expiration_Date = DATEADD(MM, 14, Registration_Date),
       Trial_Expired =
           CASE
             WHEN DATEADD(MM, 14, Registration_Date) < GETDATE() THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
           END
WHERE ... -- some condition here
```

Comment: Afaik you have to use the `DateAdd` function to add days to a date. Also, the column `Trial_expired` will not get updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed field for `Trial_Expired` instead.

```
CREATE TABLE Membership
    (
    Registration_Date DATE, 
    Trial_Expiration_Date DATE,
    Trial_Expired AS  CASE
             WHEN Trial_Expiration_Date < GETDATE() THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
           END
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
```